# Railscasts #241 NoMethodError undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, railscasts

There is a NoMethodError in SessionsController#create. The twitter authentication page occurs but the callback URL is not working. The page is not being rendered to the website after twitter authentication.
Here is the code in different files.

In routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "posts#index"

  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout

  resources :posts
end
```

In sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end
end
```

In user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

Full Trace:

```
app/models/user.rb:6:in `block in create_with_omniauth'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:40:in `create!'
app/models/user.rb:3:in `create_with_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__168269495__process_action__8122527__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:570:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:401:in `call_app!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:363:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:58:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__208198798__call__80088063__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' 
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/sakshi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/sakshi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/sakshi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Console:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:6:in `block in create_with_omniauth'
  app/models/user.rb:3:in `create_with_omniauth'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Comment: please provide stacktrace

Comment: Be sure to use the application url with IP address and port on which ur application is running

Comment: Where you getting this error with the line no. ?

Comment: check whether `auth` is nil or not in create action

Comment: @BachanSmruty 'app/models/user.rb:6:in `block in create_with_omniauth''
    'app/models/user.rb:3:in `create_with_omniauth''                    'app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in `create''

Comment: @SaschaKaestle I have provided the Full trace. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made changes in this line:

```
user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
```

and it works.

Answer (score 3):

In line 6 of `app/models/user.rb`:

```
user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
```

The `auth` hash doesn't have a value for the "user_info" key, so it returns `nil`; then you try to call the `[]` method on nil, which raises the exception.

Try adding a `p auth` in the block to verify the `auth` hash contents:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      puts "DEBUG " + "=" * 50
      p auth
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, you should be able to see it in the logs

Comment: yeah, it's supposed to, but what are the contents of the `auth` hash?

Comment: Lots of things: #<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash secret="---" token="---" including the twitter account information.

Comment: Does it have the `user_info` key?

Comment: No. It contains user_id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44964/discussion-between-sakshi-jain-and-ju-liu)

Comment: So, that's why it isn't working: you code supposes that the `auth` hash has a key `user_info` which contains another hash, while in fact you don't.